# Naming Policy for @Enumerated @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate

Within my Java application I am using Collections of Enums as follows:

```
@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
protected Set<Tag> tags = new TreeSet<>();
```

However this definition is given in `@MappedSuperClass` and so I cannot be defining `name` in `@JoinTable` as the name would collide within the child classes. My problem is that the default hibernate naming policy is ignored. For instance, for inherited class `Event` instead of table with name `event_tags`, hibernate is trying to use `Event_tags` and instead of field `event_id` it is trying to use `Event_id`. It seems to me Hibernate is completely ignoring the naming policy and just use the entity names without any change.

How can I force it to use the default naming policy?

Comment: As an unrelated note, always use `EnumSet` if your element type is an enum; it's small and extremely fast.

Comment: Well, I don't want to use EnumSet as this Enum is of size 1000 and I usually have only a few elements in the Set. If you check the implementation, you will see that it allocates memory for all the elements, which is not desired in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the default naming policy can't handle these and you are required to implement your own. For instance:

```
public class NamingPolicy implements NamingStrategy, Serializable {

    @Override
    public String classToTableName(String className) {
        return StringHelper.unqualify(className).toLowerCase();
    }



    @Override
    public String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {
        return StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName);
    }



    public String singularize(String propertyName) {
        if (propertyName != null && propertyName.endsWith("s")) {
            propertyName = propertyName.substring(0, propertyName.length() - 1);
        }

        return propertyName;
    }



    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName) {
        return tableName;
    }



    @Override
    public String columnName(String columnName) {
        return columnName;
    }



    @Override
    public String collectionTableName(
            String ownerEntity, String ownerEntityTable, String associatedEntity,
            String associatedEntityTable, String propertyName) {

        return classToTableName(ownerEntityTable) + "_" + 
                or(associatedEntityTable, singularize(propertyName));
    }



    @Override
    public String joinKeyColumnName(String joinedColumn, String joinedTable) {
        return columnName(joinedColumn);
    }



    @Override
    public String foreignKeyColumnName(
            String propertyName, String propertyEntityName,
            String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName) {

        String header = propertyName != null ? propertyName : propertyTableName;
        if (header == null) {
            throw new AssertionFailure("NamingStrategy not properly filled");
        }

        return classToTableName(header) + "_" + referencedColumnName;
    }



    @Override
    public String logicalColumnName(String columnName, String propertyName) {
        return StringHelper.isNotEmpty(columnName)
                ? columnName : StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName);
    }



    @Override
    public String logicalCollectionTableName(
            String tableName, String ownerEntityTable, String associatedEntityTable, String propertyName) {


        if (tableName != null) {
            return tableName;
        } else {
            return tableName(ownerEntityTable) + "_" + (associatedEntityTable != null
                    ? associatedEntityTable
                    : singularize(propertyName));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public String logicalCollectionColumnName(
            String columnName, String propertyName, String referencedColumn) {
        return StringHelper.isNotEmpty(columnName)
                ? columnName
                : classToTableName(propertyName) + "_" + singularize(referencedColumn);
    }
}
```